# Apache Ignite Rest API calls. (Any Ideas about Apache Ignite SDK?)

Tags: rest, api, spring-boot, microservices, ignite

We are trying to store data from XML in Apache ignite cache, which is set up in a Kubernates cluster in Azure. We have a spring boot application, added ignite dependency, parsing the XML using jaxb to pojos and storing the data. But the ignite cache put operation is taking a lot of time. ( Because we are dealing with 500K - 1M lines of XML

As an alternative, we trying to use this REST API calls provide by ignite itself in our application. (https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/rest-api)

My questions:

1. Does anybody have working example to do this in spring boot? Can it be done using Ignite SDK? (We know we can send get and put request using rest template in spring boot.)
2. Is it possible to send json response to this rest API? If so, How? Examples please.

Thanks for your response. Will help us a lot.

Comment: Is the question "how do i efficiently load 1mm lines of XML" or "how do I use the REST API"?

Comment: How to use the Apache Ignite Rest api calls from spring boot? And also how to save 1M lines XML efficiently into Ignite cache?

Answer (score 2):

If your underlying problem is loading 1mm records is too slow, using the REST interface is not the solution. Instead, you should consider using the [DataStreamer API](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/index.html), which is [designed to ingest large amounts of data](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/data-streamers). You probably also don't need to convert your XML objects into POJO, but that's an optimisation you might not need right now.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this one out. But if we have to use this REST calls for Ignite from spring boot, we would have to use rest template only from spring boot. Correct? Or is there any other way ?

Comment: You will need to be able to grab Ignite object, call java methods on it, such as `dataStreamer()`